# Postal (Zip) Code database / Address validation

Tags: location, dataset, geo, zipcode, postal-code

I have CountryCode and PostalCode and I need to get the list of cities which match options (in real-time).

I already checked out some databases and APIs as http://www.zippopotam.us or http://www.geonames.org/ but they are unusable because of lack of countries (I need countries worldwide with up-to-date information).

Another option is GoogleAPI (too expensive in our case), GeoCodeNames and Mapanet (both expensive, I'm looking to spend 400$/year maximum).

Npm packages did not help either, all I was able to found were US/Canada oriented or incomplete (I need worldwide, including middle-east and Africa).

Comment: Would this work for you?  https://mapanet.eu/EN/ - No affiliation.  I just googled it.

Comment: As mentioned in post, it is paid: http://www.mapanet.eu/Buy/

Comment: I'd love to know what you find out.  I work in the address validation field and I have found that there are two choices:  1 - paid (complete and up to date) or 2 - inexpensive/free (incomplete and out of date)

Comment: Just to sum it up, we settled with the paid option (Mapanet.eu)

Comment: Mapanet data is awful. Much data is missing and out of date. Seach for their reviews. I would recommend GeoPostCodes. The global database is about $2,000; but that is the cheapest you will get good data for. And it's not full of omissions and mistakes. Codes and jurisdictions are always changing, so their data is not 100% accurate to the day, but there is very little that is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Geocode.xyz provides this information.

for example: https://geocode.xyz/27777?region=DE

Will return:

- 20 Bökenbusch, Ganderlesee, Germany 27777 » Confidence Score: 0.5
- Ganderkesee DE 27777 Germany
- Bremen DE 27777 Germany
- Schierbrok DE 27777 Germany
- Wildeshausen DE 27777 Germany
- Delmenhorst DE 27777 Germany
- Gandereksee DE 27777 Germany
- Ganderkesee - Urneburg DE 27777 Germany
- Garderkesee / Bookholzberg DE 27777 Germany
- Immer DE 27777 Germany
- Garderkesee DE 27777 Germany
- Ganderkese-Heide DE 27777 Germany
- Ganderkesee-Bookholzberg DE 27777 Germany
- Landkreis Oldenburg DE 27777 Germany
- Hohenböken DE 27777 Germany
- Ganderlesee DE 27777 Germany